# How to read logs from the main application in Argo workflow

Tags: docker, kubernetes, argocd, argo-workflows, argo

I want to read the log file from the running application inside the main container of the Argo workflow.

I can see that the Argo workflow emits the log file to the path `/tmp/argo/outputs/logs/main.log` 
as the output of the workflow once it finishes, and then the wait container syncs this log file to the configured repository. We use the PNS as the executor, and our logs are outputted to Stdout (we do fmt.print() in our application).

Is there a way to read these logs from the running application itself from a log file? I tried to find or grep all the logs stored in the main container during the execution but couldn't find them.

I tried to find the log file in the container during the execution but couldn't locate it anywhere. I also tried to look for resources online, but there is no information regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried archiving the logs?

```
# This file describes the config settings available in the workflow controller configmap
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: workflow-controller-configmap
data:
  config: |
    instanceID: my-ci-controller
    artifactRepository:
      archiveLogs: true
      s3:
        endpoint: s3.amazonaws.com
        bucket: my-bucket
        region: us-west-2
        insecure: false
        accessKeySecret:
          name: my-s3-credentials
          key: accessKey
        secretKeySecret:
          name: my-s3-credentials
          key: secretKey
```